# Is it possible to have a variable which is a reference to a template class with different class identifiers?

Tags: c++

Here's a non-compilable code snippet:

```
priority_queue<int> lessQueue;
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> greaterQueue;

// This line can't compile.
auto q = condition() ? lessQueue : greaterQueue;
q.top(); // and lots of code like q.push(), q.pop()...
```

Is it possible to make this work?
Thanks!

Comment: Is `condition()` a `constexpr`?

Comment: @TartanLlama It could be constexpr function. However, for my usage, the |condition| has parameters and the parameters are not constexpr

Comment: Type of auto is determined at compile time. If it cannot be it will not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the pushing and popping in a templated function, then pass either `lessQueue` or `greaterQueue` depending on the condition.

Something like

```
template<typename Q>
void do_stuff(Q& queue)
{
    // Lots of pushing and popping...
}

...

if (condition())
    do_stuff(lessQueue);
else
    do_stuff(greaterQueue);
```

Comment: I know that template function works; but it's a little tedious since it's out-of-line. Maybe lambda function with auto parameter?

Comment: @Kuo-chungHsu Yes a generic lambda could also work (if your compiler supports the C++14 feature), it is essentially the same as using a templated function. The question is, would it be more or less readable (and therefore more or less maintainable)? And it would also be "out of line", as you need to define the lambda separately and then call it like in my answer anyway. And I would personally discourage large lambdas in favor of actual functions.

Comment: template function can not in a block-scope. I guess lambda works for block-scope?

Answer (score 3):

Not really. The `?:` operator requires that the two optional results are either of the same type, or one is convertible to the other. Here, that doesn't seem to be the case.

The use of `auto` has a similar requirement - the resulting type has to be fixed at compile time (static typing). It cannot be of different types for different calls to the containing function, for example.